# Equivalent of parameterString NSURL in URL

Tags: ios, swift, url, nsurl

I have particular uri to parse, previously I did it using `NSURL` and `parameterString` property, I would like to migrate code to Swift, but now I see that this property is no longer available in `URL` structure.

deep link example: `//home;type=O;name=bob;surname=hhh;hasCar=YES;`

Using `parameterString` I have got `type=O;name=bob;surname=hhh;hasCar=YES` result.

I can't find similar working method/property in Swift `URL` structure. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Look into `URLComponents`.

Comment: @rmaddy I have looked before, but please tell me, what exactly you have in mind?

Comment: That URL has only a *host* and no query parameters at all. I don't see how `NSURL.parameterString` would give the intended result in your case.

Comment: @MartinR See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl about the difference between `query` and `parameterString`. It is actually omitted in `URLComponents` too.

Comment: @Sulthan: But `NSURL(string: "//home;type=O;name=bob;surname=hhh;hasCar=YES;")?.parameterString` returns nil ...

Comment: @MartinR True, there is one `/` missing for it to be valid parameter string.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the documentation, there is no equivalent. To be honest, I have never seen that used since everybody seems to be using `query` instead. To access it, you will have to revert to `NSURL`:

```
let url = URL(string: "//home/;type=O;name=bob;surname=hhh;hasCar=YES;")!
let parameterString = (url as NSURL).parameterString
print(parameterString) // "type=O;name=bob;surname=hhh;hasCar=YES;"
```

It seems to me that `NSURL` is based on [RFC 1808](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808) while `URL` is based on [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).

Comment: And that gives `nil` with the URL in the question (as does `NSURL(string: "//home;type=O;name=bob;surname=hhh;hasCar=YES;")?.parameterString`)

Comment: @MartinR True but the truth is there is no equivalent for `parameterString` on `URL`.

Comment: Good catch about RFC 1808 vs 3986! Btw, the “real” URL could also be `///home;type=O;...`